# Basic Block instrumentation

Tags: llvm

I want to insert a counter to record how many times the basic block executed.

The steps I took:

1. I write an LLVM instrumentation pass named `BlockProfiling.cpp`
2. I compile it with:

   ```
   $ g++ -c BlockProfiling.cpp _i/usr/local/include `llvm-config --cxxflag`
   ```

   it generates a file named `BlockPrpfiling.o`
3. I run:

   ```
   $ g++ -shared -o BlockProfiling.so BlockProfiling.o -L/usr/local/lib `llvm-config --ldflags -libs`
   ```

   it generates a shared library named `BlockProfiling.so`
4. I use it to instrument my file `test.bc` and generate `test.bb.bc`:

   ```
   $opt -load=./BlockProfiling.so -insert-bb-profling test.bc -o test.bb.bc
   ```
5. I use llvm-diff to confirm it's done.

But when I use lli to execute test.bb.bc, there comes an error said:

> LLVM ERROR: Program used external function 'llvm_start_func_profiling' which could not be resolved!

Any solutions?

The llvm version is 3.3 and here is my code:

```
namespace{
struct BlockProfiler: public ModulePass{
    static char ID;
    BlockProfiler():ModulePass(ID) {
        initializeBlock ProfilerPass(*Registry::getPassRegistry());
    }

    virtual bool runOnModule(Module &M);
};  //end of function profiling pass

}  //end of namespace

char BlockProfiler::ID = 0 ;
INITIALIZE_PASS(BlockProfiler, "insert-block-profiling",
    "Insert instrumentation for profiling", false, false )

ModulePass *llvm::createBlockProfilerPass() {return new BlockProfiler() ;  }


//static RegisterPass<BlockProfilerPass> Y("insert-block-profiling", 
                                           "Insert instrumentation for block profiling");

bool BlockProfiler::runOnModule(Module &M){
Function *Main = M.getFunction("main") ;
if(Main == 0)
{
    errs()<<" WARING: cannot insert block profiling into a module"
        <<" with no main function. \n" ;
    return false ; // no main, no instrumentation, and no modify
}

unsigned NumBlocks = 0;
for(Module::iterator I = M.begin(), E = M.end(); I != E ; ++I)
    NumBlocks += I->size(); 

Type *ATy = ArrayType::get(Type::getInt32Ty(M.getContext()), NumBlocks) ;
GlobalVariable *Counters = 
    new GlobalVariable(M, ATy, false, GlobalValue::InternalLinkage,
        Constant::getNullValue(ATy), "BlockProCounters") ;

//Instrument all of the blocks
    unsigned i = 0;
    for(Module::iterator I = M.begin(), E = M.end(); I != E; ++I){
        for(Function::iterator BB = I->begin(), E = I->end() ; BB != E; ++BB )
            //Insert counter at the start of the block
            IncrementCounterInBlock(BB, i++, Counters);
    }

    //add the initialization call to main
    InsertProfilingInitCall(Main, "llvm_start_block_profiling", Counters); 
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to pass `-load=libprofile_rt.so` to `lli` as well, so it will load the runtime library for profiling - that's the one that contains the `llvm_start_block_profiling` function.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have not write a llvm_start_block_profiling function, so there is not a llvm_start_block_profiling in shared library libprofile_rt.so. I will add one by myself and recompile it. Thanks very much.